# Prayaschitta for plucking tulasi leaves on Dwadasi

Tags: vaishnavism, prayaschitta, tulasi

I have a question what is the  'prayaschitta', if unknowingly one plucks tulasi leaves on the Dwadasi day ?

Also does the rule regarding the prohibition on plucking tulasi leaves on Dwadasi Tithis apply when Ekadasi is not shuddya and fasting is on Dwadasi ( as Ekadasi fasting)?

Please can someone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 2):

There is [shloka](http://www.prabhupada-iskcon.de/tulasi/tulasi-mantras.html) to be chanted:

> tulasi amṛta-janmāsi sadā tvaṁ keśava-priya
> keśavārthaṁ cinomi tvāṁ varadā bhava śobhane

to ask for permission and forgiveness when plucking tulsi leaves for cause of Keshava Puja.

It must not be plucked on Tuesday, Sundays, or at night, or Dvadashi.

The workaround is to pick a bunch on a previous day, or use naturally fallen leaves.